# A particular Taylor Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

As we know, the Taylor Expansion we usually see is

\begin{equation}
e^W = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{W^n}{n!} 
\end{equation}

but today I see another equation:

\begin{equation}
e^{-W}+We^{-W} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\frac{W^n}{n!}
\end{equation}

I can not figure out how did they derive out the second equation.

I saw these when trying to solve a exercise on a probability exercise manual.

Please support and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure of the negative signs?

Comment: I also feel strange about the negative sign on the exponential, but since these are from the solution manual, so I kind of can not confirm my doubt...

Comment: I think the solution manual is wrong, as in there's a typo. You might want to read what's there right after it to see what result it uses.

Comment: Ah I see, in the next step they multiple the equation by a factor of (e^(-W))*W,  then they get the final result W+W^2, yes now I confirm the intermediate step of this solution is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$We^W=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{W^{n+1}}{n!}$

Now, differentiate both sides,

$We^W+e^W=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)\frac{W^{n}}{n!}$

Thus, we have the desired result.

Comment: OP wanted $We^{-W}+e^{-W}$

Comment: The exponential should be positive.

Comment: @CatherineChen If the exponential is positive how come you marked his answer as correct?

Comment: @Aleksandar She actually wanted $We^W+e^W$. Read her comment on the original post.

Comment: @Aleksandar I actually want to mark both correct but I can only mark one...Hasan derive it from one direction and you derive it from another direction, so both of your answers are correct. So the solution manual is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{-W}+We^{-W}=(W+1)e^{-W}=(W+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-W)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(W+1)(-W)^n}{n!}$$

I believe you are wrong.

Comment: Yes your derivation is correct.